# Phonon Density of State

Tags: condensed-matter, phonons, density-of-states

Suppose there is a material such as **graphane** which has two atoms, **Carbon** and **Hydrogen** (I mean that it has two or more atoms). How can I calculate phonon Density of State (DoS) for such system? Can I calculate DoS separately for each atoms and then sum those to obtain total DoS? Is this correct:
$$
D_{C}(\omega)=\frac {m_{C}}{k_b T} \int_0^{\infty} \frac {\langle V_C(0)V_C(t)\rangle}{\langle V_C(0)V_C(0)\rangle} dt
$$
and
$$
D_{H}(\omega)=\frac {m_{H}}{k_b T} \int_0^{\infty} \frac {\langle V_H(0)V_H(t)\rangle}{\langle V_H(0)V_H(0)\rangle} dt
$$
Therefore,

$$
D_\mathrm{system}(\omega) = D_{C}(\omega)+D_{H}(\omega)
$$

If this is correct, please provide me a reference, so I can refer to it.

Comment: I think this might be a question of the photon energy. For very high energy where the Bandstructure of graphene is not important, this might be a reasonable approch. But surely, in the energy where the band structure is important, this approximation will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks. But I mean **phonon** and not **photon**.

Comment: oh, sorry, my mistsake

Answer (score 1):

Yes you sum the DOS of the individual species to obtain the total DOS. See equation 7b here:

> [Vashishta, P., Rajiv K. Kalia, and I. Ebbsjö. "Structural
>   correlations and phonon density of states in GeSe 2: A
>   molecular-dynamics study of molten and amorphous states." Physical
>   Review B 39.9 (1989): 6034.](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.39.6034)